# How to check the text is only in numbering form after data is input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How to valid the text after the data is insert into the textbook `with same class numb`. `If input with alphabet, it will pop out with alert or window at the same time`. The data `should be only insert with numbering form`. The NaN will not be show out again.
HTML should be continue use by oninput or  oncheck or other on function?

This is just for Javascript

Below down is my code for calculation :

```js
function chicken()
{
    var foodchicken=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var chicken = theForm.elements["chicken"];
    var ttlchicken = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;

    if(chicken.checked===true)
    {
        foodchicken = ttlchicken*10;
    }
    return foodchicken;
}

function pork() 
{
    var foodpork=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var pork = theForm.elements["pork"];
    var ttlpork = document.getElementById("textbox2").value;

    if(pork.checked===true)
    {
        foodpork = ttlpork*20;
    }
    return foodpork;
}

function calculateTotal()
{
var HMontotalco = chicken() + pork() ;
var hmco = document.getElementById('totalHMonthCst').innerHTML = +HMontotalco.toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
    <div id="all">
        <form  id="energyform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>
               <br/>
                <label for='chicken' class="chick">Chicken </label></hr>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chicken" name='chicken' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <input type="text" oninput="calculateTotal();" id="textbox1" name="textbox1" placeholder="Enter total chicken" />
<br/>
<br/>
                <label for='pork' class="pig">&nbsp Pork &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label></hr>
                <input type="checkbox" id="pork" name='pork' onchange="calculateTotal();allvalidate();personvalidate()">
                <input type="text" oninput="calculateTotal();" id="textbox2" name="textbox2" placeholder="Enter total pork in kg" />
<br/>      
                <div id="totalHMonthCst">0</div>
                       </div>  
       </form>
                    </div>

</body>
              </html>
```

Comment: `if (isNaN(ttlchicken)) { alert('hey!'); return 0; }` Or, use a `type="number"` input.

Comment: Thx a lot ! if work after i edit some things